# Converting a date to a numeric timestamp in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a query wherein one of the columns is a `DATE` type. I'm trying to convert that to the nanosecond representation of the timestamp associated with the date:

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-15 | 1657843200000000000 |
| 2022-07-18 | 1658102400000000000 |
| 2022-07-19 | 1658188800000000000 |

I can get a timestamp from a date by doing this:

```
SELECT TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_VARCHAR($1))
FROM (
    SELECT DATE($1) FROM VALUES ('2022-07-15'), ('2022-07-18'), ('2022-07-19'))
```

but using `TRY_TO_NUMERIC` doesn't work so I'm not sure what to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the datediff function to return the nanoseconds since the start of the Unix epoch, which is 1970-01-01:

```
with source_data as
(
    select 
    COLUMN1::date as INPUT
    from (values
    ('2022-07-15'),
    ('2022-07-18'),
    ('2022-07-19')
    )
)
select   INPUT
        ,datediff(nanoseconds, '1970-01-01'::date, INPUT) as OUTPUT
from SOURCE_DATA
;
```

| INPUT | OUTPUT |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-15 | 1657843200000000000 |
| 2022-07-18 | 1658102400000000000 |
| 2022-07-19 | 1658188800000000000 |

Comment: I took your code and embedded it into a UDF. Thanks very much!